# Android: Using AdMob with less than 320dip width

Tags: android, admob, android-screen-support, density-independent-pixel

I'm displaying my app within a dialog. The dialog doesn't cover the full screenwith (at least 320dip). Therefore, using AdMob is a bit of a problem, because all AdSizes I've seen take up at least 320dip width. So my question is: is there a possibility to still use AdMob, but with a ad less than 320dip wide (about 280dip or so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer No. Long answer is you are probably looking at this wrong.

But what do you mean "I'm display my app within a dialog"?

If you have applied a dialog style to your app or are even dispalying all of your UI within a dialog (weird) then you can always configure a dialog to have any width. So make it 320 dip.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like no. You can have a look at the documentation https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/smart-banners

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution, but may be a work around:
This will force the adView to be smaller. It will chop off some pixels, but the overall result may be good enough.

```
 final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(m_width,//
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    adView.setLayoutParams(params);
    adView.loadAd(adReqBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Will it still load the add?